# Malloc in C language

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//function prototypes
void printRecords(char **, char **, float *, int);
int addNewRecord(char **, char **, float *, int);
int deleteRecords(char **, char **, float *, int);
void searchRecordByLastName(char **, char **, float *, int);
void sortByScores(char **, char **, float *, int);
void sortByLastName(char **, char **, float *, int);
void medianScoredStudents(char **, char **, float *, int);

//main function
int main()
{

   //declare the 2D pointer variables
   char **firstName, **lastName;
   //single dimenstional variables
   float *scores;
   //integer variables
   int count = 5, choice;
   int i = 0, j = 0;

   //allocate dynamic memory
   firstName = (char **)malloc(20 * sizeof(char **));
   lastName = (char **)malloc(20 * sizeof(char **));
   scores = (float *)malloc(20 * sizeof(float));
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       firstName[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
       lastName[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));

   }

   //prompt the user to enter the values
   printf("Working with student records: \n");
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       printf("Enter first name: ");
       scanf("%s", firstName[i]);
       printf("Enter second name: ");
       scanf("%s", lastName[i]);
       printf("Enter score: ");
       scanf("%f", &scores[i]);
   }
   //print the details
   printf("The details of student records are: \n");
   printRecords(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
   printf("\n");

   //print the menu driven functionality
   do
   {
       printf("\n");
       printf("Menu for student records \n");
       printf("1. Print records\n");
       printf("2. Add a new record\n");
       printf("3. Delete record(s)\n");
       printf("4. Search by last name\n");
       printf("5. Sort by score\n");
       printf("6. Sort by last name\n");
       printf("7. Median of the records\n");
       printf("8. Exit Application \n");
       printf("\n");

       //prompt the user to enter the choice
       printf("Enter your choice: ");
       scanf("%d", &choice);
       switch (choice)
       {
           case 1:
               //call the printRecords function
               printRecords(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 2:
               //call the addNewRecord function
               count = addNewRecord(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 3:
               //call the deleteRecords function
               count = deleteRecords(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 4:
               //call the searchRecordByLastName function
               searchRecordByLastName(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 5:
               //call the sortByScores function to sort the records
               sortByScores(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
           //call the printRecords function to print the records
               printRecords(firstName, lastName, scores, count);;
               break;
           case 6:
               //call the sortByLastName function to sort the records
               sortByLastName(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
           //call the printRecords function to print the records
               printRecords(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 7:
               //call the sortByScores function to sort the records
               sortByScores(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
           //call the medianScoredStudents function to find median value
           //print the records above the median
               medianScoredStudents(firstName, lastName, scores, count);
               break;
           case 8:
               //exit the program
               printf("Exiting the program\n");
               return 0;
               break;
           default:
               printf("Choice not in Menu ,Exit the program\n");
               break;
       }
   } while (1);
   return 0;
}
//Method definition of printRecords: prints records of all students
void printRecords(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   int i = 0;
   printf("------------------------------------------------------- \n");
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       printf("First Name: %10s, Second Name: %10s, Score: %5.2f\n", firstName[i], lastName[i], scores[i]);
   }
   printf("------------------------------------------------------- \n");
}
//addNewRecord – add a record of a student to the existing list
int addNewRecord(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   printf("\nTo add the record, enter the prompted details.\n");

   firstName[count] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
   lastName[count] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
   scores[count] = (float)malloc(sizeof(float));

   printf("Enter first name: ");
   scanf("%s", firstName[count]);
   printf("Enter second name: ");
   scanf("%s", lastName[count]);
   printf("Enter score: ");
   scanf("%f", &scores[count]);
   count = count + 1;
   return count;
}

//deleteRecords – deletes a record of a student to the existing list
int deleteRecords(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   int i = 0;
   char *name;
   printf("\nTo delete a record from the list, enter the last name.\n");
   name = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
   printf("Enter last name to delete: ");
   scanf("%s", name);
   int counter = count;
   for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
   {
       if (strcmp(lastName[i], name) == 0)
       {
           for(j = i; j<count; j++)
           {
               lastName[j] = lastName[j + 1];
               firstName[j] = firstName[j + 1];
               scores[j] = scores[j + 1];          
           }
           counter--;
       }      
   }
   count = counter;
   return count;
}
//searchRecordByLastName – searches a record of a student in the existing list
//by last name and prints the respective details
void searchRecordByLastName(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   int i = 0;
   char *name;
   name = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
   printf("\nTo search a record from the list, enter the last name.\n");
   printf("Enter last name to search: ");
   scanf("%s", name);
   int bool = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       if (strcmp(lastName[i], name) == 0)
       {
printf("First Name: %10s, Second Name: %10s, Score: %5.2f\n", firstName[i], lastName[i], scores[i]);
           bool = 1;
       }
   }
   if (bool == 0)
       printf("Sorry! Unable to find the record.\n");
}

//sortByScores – sorts a student records by the scores
void sortByScores(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   char *Ftemp = NULL;
   char *Ltemp = NULL;
   float temp = 0;
   int i, j;
   printf("\nSort the records by their scores.\n");
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       for (j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
       {
           if (scores[j] < (scores[i]))
           {

               Ftemp = firstName[j];
               firstName[j] = firstName[i];
               firstName[i] = Ftemp;

               Ltemp = lastName[j];
               lastName[j] = lastName[i];
               lastName[i] = Ltemp;

               temp = scores[j];
               scores[j] = scores[i];
               scores[i] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
}

//sortByLastName – sorts a student records by the last names
void sortByLastName(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   char *Ftemp = NULL;
   char *Ltemp = NULL;
   float temp = 0;
   int i, j;
   printf("\nSort the records by their last names.\n");
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       for (j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
       {
           if (strcmp(lastName[j], (lastName[i])) < 0)
           {
               Ftemp = firstName[j];
               firstName[j] = firstName[i];
               firstName[i] = Ftemp;

               Ltemp = lastName[j];
               lastName[j] = lastName[i];
               lastName[i] = Ltemp;

               temp = scores[j];
               scores[j] = scores[i];
               scores[i] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
}

//medianScoredStudents – finds the median value and print the recodrs at the median
//and displays the records those are above median value
void medianScoredStudents(char **firstName, char **lastName, float *scores, int count)
{
   int median = 0, i;
   printf("\nFind the median of the records and printing the records above median.\n");
   if (count % 2 != 0)
   {
       median = count / 2;
       printf("The median score is: %0.2f\n", scores[median]);
   }
   else
   {
       median = count / 2;
       printf("The first median score is: %0.2f\n", scores[median]);
       printf("The second median score is: %0.2f\n", scores[median + 1]);
   }
   for (i = 0; i < median; i++)
   {
       printf("First Name: %10s, Second Name: %10s, Score: %5.2f\n", firstName[i], lastName[i], scores[i]);
   }
}
```

I keep having errors when I use malloc in the function add new record it keeps saying 'incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’' and 'pointer value used where a floating point value was expected' and I do not know why does anybody has any suggestions here is what I have so far and this is in C.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not very clear what you are asking. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), complete, short code that shows the problem. May I also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: firstname = malloc(20*sizeof(char*));

Comment: He allocated 15 chars for 5 firstnames/lastnames

Comment: There are several things wrong with `float *scores` too, but the code is too long and rambling to quickly pin it down, I keep having to delete wrong comments.

Comment: One thing wrong is `scores[count] = (float)malloc(sizeof(float));`. You can't sensibly cast a pointer to `float` but removing the cast still leaves a compiler error. Also please `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Wrong type used in `firstName = (char **)malloc(20 * sizeof(char **));`.  Suggest re-code and don't use type. `firstName = malloc(sizeof *firstname * 20);`  Alos in `scores[count] = (float)malloc(sizeof(float));`. Change to `scores[count] = malloc(sizeof *(scores[count]));`

Comment: The error message "`incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function malloc()`" means you did not `#include <stdlib.h>`.